# error: type EventListener does not take parameters implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-codelab

I had this error when i was following https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/#4

```
public abstract class FirestoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>
    implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{

@Override
public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    //handle errors
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onEvent:error", e);
        return;
    }

 }
```

the goal of the code was to display data from the firebase

Answer (score 2):

You probably imported the wrong EventListener.  Delete the import you have now, and be sure to pick the one from Firestore instead next time.